# EF Core: An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this error from my web app hosted in Azure. It runs ok for a few days and then suddenly stops working.

Is there an issue with the connection perhaps? Which object reference does not have an instance?

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss [Error] An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferAllAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryContext.<RegisterValueBufferCursorAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.<_FirstOrDefault>d__82`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at MyProject.Data.SectionRepository.<GetByTypePathAndAlias>d__6.MoveNext() in /Users/webaccount/myproject/src/MyProject.Data/Repositories/SectionRepository.cs:line 34
```

There's nothing special about my repository or entity code.

```
public async Task<Section> GetByTypeId(string typeId) 
{
    var sections = from s in this.DbContext.Sections
        where s.TypeId == typeId
        select s;

    return await sections.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); // <-- LINE 34
}
```

This is my entity.

```
public class Section
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Is it related to this perhaps? https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8026

Will it help if I convert my repository methods to sync and staying async at the Controller?

Comment: Can you provide your connection string?  Maybe you need to add "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" in it

Comment: It is false. I'll set it to true and give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: After setting it to True and letting it run, again it works. In a few days, I now get another error: "The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets." I'm not sure why I'm getting that when it worked a few times.

Answer (score 2):

> It runs ok for a few days and then suddenly stops working.
>
> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Firstly, you can try to [remote debug your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) and check the `this.DbContext`.

Secondly, you can create/use a context instance per request, and [this artciel shows some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx), you can check it.

Comment: I'll try setting MARS to true as suggested by hugorgor. I can't do an instance per request because I'd like the DbContext to be injected. Is it possible to do per request but still injected from somewhere outside of the repository?

Comment: It seems that you are using Dependency injection framework, please try to use a DI container to inject DbContext instances with a PerWebRequest lifetime.

Comment: Isn't Transient the default lifetime? That's equivalent to per web request, I think.

Comment: This is what I have: "services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(appDbContextConnectionString));"

Comment: ``Isn't Transient the default lifetime? That's equivalent to per web request`` [Scoped lifetime services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options) will be created once per request.

Comment: I just checked. "The default for AddDbContext is Scoped meaning that during a web request all classes will be accessing the same SqlContext." That should be ok right?