# An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Volo.Saas.EntityFrameworkCore.SaasDbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core, abp

- **ABP Framework version:** v4.4.3
- **UI type**: MVC
- **DB provider**: EF Core
- **Tiered (MVC) or Identity Server Separated (Angular)**:  yes

**Exception message and stack trace**:

2021-11-03 21:21:43.774 -05:00 [ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Volo.Saas.EntityFrameworkCore.SaasDbContext'.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.BufferedDataRecord.InitializeAsync(DbDataReader reader, IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.BufferedDataRecord.InitializeAsync(DbDataReader reader, IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
2021-11-03 21:21:43.838 -05:00 [ERR] A task was canceled.
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.BufferedDataRecord.InitializeAsync(DbDataReader reader, IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.InitializeAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 columns, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.EntityFrameworkCore.EfCoreRepository`3.FindAsync(TKey id, Boolean includeDetails, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.ProceedAsync() at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation) at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.InterceptAsync[TResult](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func`3 proceed) at Volo.Saas.Tenants.TenantStore.GetCacheItemAsync(Nullable`1 id, String name)
at Volo.Saas.Tenants.TenantStore.FindAsync(Guid id)
at ClientsLink.Data.ClientsLinkTenantDatabaseMigrationHandler.MigrateAndSeedForTenantAsync(Guid tenantId, String adminEmail, String adminPassword) in D:\Century\Internal\Clients.Link\Clients.Link\src\ClientsLink.Domain\Data\ClientsLinkTenantDatabaseMigrationHandler.cs:line 98

**This is occurring on the highlighted line of code below:**

```
private async Task MigrateAndSeedForTenantAsync(
    Guid tenantId,
    string adminEmail,
    string adminPassword)
{
  try
  {
    using (_currentTenant.Change(tenantId))
    {
      // Create database tables if needed
      using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(requiresNew: true, isTransactional: false))
      {
        var tenantConfiguration = await _tenantStore.FindAsync(tenantId); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        if (tenantConfiguration?.ConnectionStrings != null &&
            !tenantConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.Default.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
          foreach (var migrator in _dbSchemaMigrators)
          {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Running migration {migrator.ToString()}");
            await migrator.MigrateAsync();
          }
        }

        await uow.CompleteAsync();
      }
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue**:

1. Use ABP Commercial Suite v 4.4.3 to generate a Sample Tiered MVC application
2. Add a couple of entities - one global and one multitenant with a navigation property to the global one
3. Create a Sample database
4. Run the DbMigrator - host database will be migrated successfully
5. Run the web application, login as admin, create a new Test tenant - after about a minute, the UI reports an Internal Error and the exception above is logged

It seems fairly obvious after working this for two weeks, there is something preventing the execution of the _tenantStore.FindAsync(tenantId)  call.

**What possible things could cause that call to timeout or be canceled?**

Please think about your response and be as verbose as possible.

I have swapped out every component. I have built and rebuilt on two separate machines. I have rewritten my data seed contributors. I have swapped out System.Data.SqlClient for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient  and set the Command Timeout connection string argument two 3600. Nothing I have tried in two weeks is resolving this issue.

Comment: Looks like task was cancelled. Probably because HTTP request timed out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query ... A task was canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715219/an-exception-occurred-while-iterating-over-the-results-of-a-query-a-task-was)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an answer in this post: https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/2084/An-exception-occurred-while-iterating-over-the-results-of-a-query-for-context-type-%27VoloSaasEntityFrameworkCoreSaasDbContexspendinng

[image: Screenshot showing requiresNew arguments set to false]

As you see from the screenshot, the solution was setting the requiresNew arguments to false. This is necessary because there was already a transaction in process started by the `[UnitOfWork]` attribute on a calling method.